# XNA - No loading screen or menu

Tags: c#, xna

The problem is that it just shows a black screen and the loading mouse. It doesn't show the loading screen or the menu.

```cs
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    SpriteBatch mBatch;
    Texture2D mTheQuantumBros2;
    MenuComponent menuComponent;
    public static Rectangle screen;
    public static string GameState = "Menu";
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        mBatch = new SpriteBatch(this.graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        ContentManager aLoader = new ContentManager(this.Services);
        aLoader.RootDirectory = "Content";
        mTheQuantumBros2 = aLoader.Load<Texture2D>("TheQuantumBros2") as Texture2D;
        menuComponent.LoadContent(Content);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        
    }

    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        switch (GameState)
        {
            case "Menu":
                menuComponent.Update(gameTime);
            break;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        switch (GameState)
        {
            case "Menu":
                menuComponent.Draw(spriteBatch);
                break;
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
class MenuComponent
{
    KeyboardState keyboard;
    KeyboardState prevKeyboard;

    SpriteBatch mBatch;
    Texture2D mTheQuantumBros2;

    GameTime gameTime;

    MouseState mouse;
    MouseState prevMouse;

    SpriteFont spriteFont;

    List<string> buttonList = new List<string>();

    int selected = 0;

    public MenuComponent()
    {
        buttonList.Add("Campaign");
        buttonList.Add("Multiplayer");
        buttonList.Add("Zombies");
        buttonList.Add("Quit Game");

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font");
    }
    
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Up))
        {
            if (selected > 0) selected--;
        }

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Down))
        {
            if (selected < buttonList.Count - 1) selected++;
        }

        prevMouse = mouse;
        prevKeyboard = keyboard;
    }

    public bool CheckMouse()
    {
        return (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released);
    }

    public bool CheckKeyboard(Keys key)
    {
        return (keyboard.IsKeyDown(key) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key));
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        Color color;
        int linePadding = 3;

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        mBatch.Begin();
        mBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height), Color.White);
        if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds <= 3)
        {
            mBatch.End();
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
            {
                color = (i == selected) ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.Gold;
                spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2((Game1.screen.Width / 2) - (spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X / 2), (Game1.screen.Height / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose of this statement: `(gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds <= 3)`? 
Also, you are never updating the game time in the menu component. So, the aforementioned code would behave unexpectedly.

You are also calling spriteBatch.Begin() twice before end is called... So that should be giving you an error. Check those for issues.

EDIT: Since you are only calling spriteBatch.End() IF less than 3 seconds have passed, it will never be called again after that? I think.

As a potential fix... I would try only calling spriteBatch.Begin() and spriteBatch.End() inside of game1.cs. So:

```
//In your menu class
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    Color color;
    int linePadding = 3;


    if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds <= 3)
    { 
        mBatch.Begin();
        mBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height), Color.White);
        mBatch.End(); 
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
        {
            color = (i == selected) ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.Gold;
            spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2((Game1.screen.Width / 2) - (spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X / 2), (Game1.screen.Height / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
        }
    }
}
```

And back in game1.cs, call spriteBatch.End() right before base.Draw() is called.

In general, it is best to only use one spriteBatch, I believe it is simply faster than beginning and ending two different batches.

EDIT 2:

Just uhm... copy and paste I guess. It works fine after the adjustments I made (you can read about them at the bottom).

You're refactored code:

game1.cs:

```
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    MenuComponent menuComponent;

    public static Rectangle screen;
    public static string GameState = "Menu";
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
        //graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        menuComponent = new MenuComponent();
        menuComponent.LoadContent(Content, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        switch (GameState)
        {
            case "Menu":
                menuComponent.Update(gameTime);
            break;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        switch (GameState)
        {
            case "Menu":
                menuComponent.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime);
                break;
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }
```

MenuComponent:

```
    KeyboardState keyboard;
    KeyboardState prevKeyboard;

    MouseState mouse;
    MouseState prevMouse;

    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
    Texture2D mTheQuantumBros2;

    SpriteFont spriteFont;

    List<string> buttonList = new List<string>();

    int selected = 0;
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
    public MenuComponent()
    {
        buttonList.Add("Campaign");
        buttonList.Add("Multiplayer");
        buttonList.Add("Zombies");
        buttonList.Add("Quit Game");

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content, int _screenWidth, int _screenHeight)
    {
        spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font");
        mTheQuantumBros2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("TheQuantumBros2");

        screenHeight = _screenHeight;
        screenWidth = _screenWidth;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Up))
        {
            if (selected > 0) selected--;
        }

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Down))
        {
            if (selected < buttonList.Count - 1) selected++;
        }

        prevMouse = mouse;
        prevKeyboard = keyboard;
    }

    public bool CheckMouse()
    {
        return (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released);
    }

    public bool CheckKeyboard(Keys key)
    {
        return (keyboard.IsKeyDown(key) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key));
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Color color;
        int linePadding = 3;

        if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds <= 3)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height), Color.White);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
            {
                color = (i == selected) ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.Gold;
                spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2((screenWidth / 2) - (spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X / 2), (screenHeight / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
            }
        }
    }
```

There were a bunch of little issues. For example, you were setting the menuComp = to a new menu component on every update call, so all the old variables in there would be lost, hence there was no images loading. SpriteBatch.Begin() was being called twice in a row, and then end was being called twice in a row. One spriteBatch (from game1.cs preferrably) should be used to draw. By sending that spritebatch through the method, you do not need to call begin again, and it is simply better not to for performance reasons. Last thing I noticed (that I can think of) was that the graphics device was not being set to anything because you were constantly creating a new version of it. Oh also, you were calling graphicsDevice.Clear() way too early, this only should be called once per draw (at the beginning, so old graphical info is removed from the screen).

Comment: The purpose of the statement is to stop showing the image after 3 seconds. Is there a better way to change it? And spriteBatch.Begin() is only called once in each class. What would you recommend I do to fix it?

Comment: But... why? Doesn't the user need time to select from the menu? :p

Comment: The 3 seconds is for the image displayed before the menu.

Comment: Oh I see, but then the menu items are also drawn within the same if statement, and are only drawn with the image... Right?

Comment: How would you "erase" what was drawn so you can use the same spriteBatch?

Comment: That is what GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black) is for. It clears the screen of all previous values. After calling .Clear(), only the new objects you draw will appear.

Comment: I'm still having problems, do you have any more ideas?

Comment: You should post the updated code so we know what you have changed so far.

Comment: In the other answer, Odrai said I should upload my project and share it. Where would I do that?

Comment: You're awesome. Sorry for all the mistakes, I'm like only half a brain. :P So now it works but the menu only goes up or down to the top or bottom, not in between.

Comment: Also, thanks for explaining instead of only giving the way to fix it. It really helps me learn. :P

Comment: Yeah, that is because the game is updating to fast. When you press the key, it is counting it like 5 times before you let go. So, to fix that you will need to keep track of the previous keyboard state. If the previous keyboard state is down (as in the key is pressed) and the current state is key up, then it means you have pressed and released the button. And at the point, change the selected index.

Comment: Okay so I put the thread to sleep for 250 ms but is there a way to do it like every click instead of when it's down?

Comment: In your CheckKeyBoard method, change the return method to this: `(keyboard.IsKeyUp(key) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key)`. The difference is KeyUp, meaning the button has been released. So the cursor will not move until the key has been released.

Comment: That makes sense, sorry for all the questions but I have more. How would you make the selected one show like |  (Selected)  | instead of only the color. And I am trying something, if I can't figure it out then I'll ask that too :/

Comment: So with your proposed fix, it goes to the second button, then no longer works moves up or down

Comment: I think you should make a new post so this one doesn't get more bloated. I'll help out on that one too. I have an idea/solution but its long.

Comment: There's the URL, I'm going to call it a night. You can answer the question on that page whenever you have free time. Thanks for all the help (:

Comment: Can you help with this one please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600198/xna-how-to-dim-a-section-of-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

I debugged your program/code and there are a few problems:

- There is a declaration of MenuComponent menuComponent, but you didn't create an instance in the Game1() constructor. So add: menuComponent = new MenuComponent()
- There is a declaration of SpriteBatch mBatch, but you didn't create an instance in the MenuComponent() constructor. So create one. The same for GameTime gameTime variable.

At the moment I don't have SpriteFont and TheQuantumBros2 texture. Is it possible that you upload your project and share it?

Comment: Yes, good catches, OP placed mBatch = new mBatch() in the wrong class.

Comment: The same for mTheQuantumBros2 variable. One declaration in Game and one in MenuComponent.

Best way to solve the problems is to debug your program :)

Comment: When I debug it just shows a black screen as I said. SpriteFont is just a .spritefont with Agency FB as the font. How/Where would I upload my project?

Comment: Share for e.g. a Dropbox link or upload a .zip of your project at http://dfiles.eu/ and share that link. As soon as I have your project I will help you to solve the problems.