# XNA - How to dim a section of the screen?

Tags: c#, xna

How would you dim an image(or a section of the screen) so that you can show something else that's not dimmed as the focus? Sorry that it's a little vague and hard to understand, but I can't think of a better way to phrase it.

Comment: What is going to be dimmed and how often?

Comment: You could look into shaders, I have no experience with them, but if you want a simpler fix, you could use a big texture2d, color everything on the texture a dark transparent color except where the highlighted object resides.

Comment: I want to dim the entire screen and then draw on top of the dim so the drawing on top won't be dimmed. And this will happen every time a button is pressed. So easiest way for this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how efficient or smart this is, but spriteBatch.Draw takes a color to shade textures. You could try setting up a list of textures and apply darker colors to the textures that are meant to be dimmed.

Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < texturesToDraw.Count; i++)
{
    if(i == selected) 
    {
         spriteBatch.Draw(texturesToDraw[i], position, Color.White)
    }
    else
    {
         spriteBatch.Draw(texturesToDraw[i], position, Color.SomeDarkColor)
    }
}
```

A simple tutorial that might help you get started: http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/fadeinfadeout/FadeInFadeOut.shtml

Comment: I understand the ideal but I cannot think of how to achieve it correctly... :P

Comment: Added a very small version of what it might look like.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me achieve my goal.